# Wrong dates in sql query when search happens in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am performing default search of rails_admin gem with between clause. It is making the following query.

```
 SELECT  `booking_reports`.* FROM `booking_reports` WHERE ((booking_reports.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-04-30 22:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-02 21:59:59.999999'))  ORDER BY booking_reports.id asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

But the query should be

```
 SELECT  `booking_reports`.* FROM `booking_reports` WHERE ((booking_reports.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-04-30 23:59:59.000000' AND '2015-05-02 23:59:59.999999'))  ORDER BY booking_reports.id asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

or

```
 SELECT  `booking_reports`.* FROM `booking_reports` WHERE ((booking_reports.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-04-30 23:59:59.000000' AND '2015-05-01 23:59:59.999999'))  ORDER BY booking_reports.id asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Please see the below image and records provided by the query

[image: Search with between clause]

Default format of the date is `IST (Thu, 01 May 2014 23:08:05 IST +05:30)`. The IST format stores into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I add this into config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'New Delhi'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'New Delhi'
```

Now the format for date is as per my timezone and also query is accurate now.